# NeoClientPHP Issue when retrieving data from Neo4J

Tags: php, neo4j, cypher, neoxygen

Currently, I am still learning the Neo4J Graph Database and plan to migrate my current RDBMS into Graph Database. So I was searching the methodology of how to connect Neo4J in PHP/Codeigniter until i found out that Neoxygen-NeoClient was the answer.

After I installed it using composer then i planning to test it. I created a new page called **connection.php** and placed in a root folder. Unfortunately right now i'm having some problem when to get data from Neo4J in my localhost and

And below is the contains of connection.php

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Neoxygen\NeoClient\ClientBuilder;
$client = ClientBuilder::create()
->addConnection('default', 'http', 'myserver.dev', 7474, true, 'username', 'password')
->build();
$q = 'MATCH (n:Actor) RETURN n.name';
$client->sendCypherQuery($q);
$result = $client->getRows();
echo $result;
?>
```

So the result from that query is not shown and i would like to ask how to display the return query from Neo4J in PHP ?

**Updated**

I was trying to testing from your example of running application in here
https://github.com/ikwattro/neo4j-neoclient-example

Then i followed your installation steps then ran it on localhost
But still couldnt display the data from Neo4J then after i check the Web Console, i got this error

> http://localhost/search?q=Matrix Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   localhost/graph Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   localhost/search?q=Matrix Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

So I guess the problem is I don't get the **graph** and **search** folder after i did composer installation and i got only **vendor** folder

```
composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader
```

Could you please verify this ? 
If that's not the case, please give me some solution to resolve this issue.

And also could you please explain what you mean to run application using

```
http://localhost:8000/import
```

Thanks before

Answer (score 1):

I'm the maintainer of NeoClient.

First, if you need to handle results, you should activate the response formatter :

```
$client = ClientBuilder::create()
->addConnection('default', 'http', 'myserver.dev', 7474, true, 'username', 'password')
->setAutoFormatResponse(true)
->build();
```

You have now multiple possibilities to get your results back :

In a table format like in the Neo4j browser :

```
$q = 'MATCH (n:Actor) RETURN n.name';
$result = $client->sendCypherQuery($q)->getResult()->getTableFormat();
```

Or, if you want to manipulate nodes and relationships objects :

```
$q = 'MATCH (n:Actor) RETURN n';
$result = $client->sendCypherQuery($q)->getResult();
$nodes = $result->getNodes();
$relationships = $result->getRelationships();
```

You can also make use of the identifier with the get method :

```
$q = 'MATCH (n:Actor) RETURN n';
$result = $client->sendCypherQuery($q)->getResult();
$actors = $result->get('n');
```

I wrote 3 articles on Sitepoint about Neo4j and PHP with NeoClient, I'm sure they can help you :

http://www.sitepoint.com/author/ikwattro/

**UPDATE**

I checked the [Neo4j-MovieDB-Repository](https://github.com/ikwattro/neo4j-moviedb-example) I did a while ago, and I updated the README with how to test it locally.

For your updated questions :

1. Make sure you run the webserver with the good root path defined, so if your current directory is $myrepo/web, then `php -S localhost:8000` will be ok, if you are in the parent directory, you need to provide the web index root as argument `php -S localhost:8000 -t web/`
2. the url `http://localhost:8000/importdb` is made in order to load data in the database, otherwise he will not find movies and actors.

If you still have errors or issues, please open a separate SO question or trigger an issue on Github https://github.com/ikwattro/neo4j-moviedb-example/issues

Comment: Firstly,  thank you for your response. Secondly I have another issue reagarding your NeoClient MovieDB Example in https://github.com/ikwattro/neo4j-neoclient-example. Please check my updated issue. Thanks